# Sorting Icelandic index correctly using LaTeX (accented characters after non-accented)

Tags: indexing, xindy

I'm using `Xindy` to make an index for my book. It sorts the words mostly correctly, but it doesn't sort accented characters *(i.e. á é í ó ú ý)* after the corresponding non-accented characters *(a e i o u y)*, unless the words are otherwise identical. For example, `Xindy` will sort 'ís' after 'is', but it will sort 'auga' after 'ás'. 
I would like it to sort ás after auga, and in general I want it to sort the accented characters after the corresponding non-accented character. For the record, this is the correct sort order:

a, á, b, c, d, ð, e, é, f, g, h, i, í, j, k, l, m, n, o, ó, p, q, r, s, t, u, ú, v, w, x, y, ý, z, þ, æ, ö

Here's my MWE:

```
% filename alphabet.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\title{My book}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Stafrófið}

Ananas\index{ananas}, ás\index{ás},
banani\index{banani}, dagblað\index{dagblað}, epli\index{epli}, ég\index{ég}, flugvél\index{flugvél}, gíraffi\index{gíraffi}, hús\index{hús}, indíáni\index{indíáni}, ís\index{ís}, jörðin\index{jörðin}, kisa\index{kisa}, lykill\index{lykill}, mús\index{mús},
nef\index{nef}, ormur\index{ormur}, óbó\index{óbó}, píanó\index{píanó}, rós\index{rós}, skæri\index{skæri}, tré\index{tré}, ugla\index{ugla}, úr\index{úr}, varir\index{varir}, yddari\index{yddari}, ýta\index{ýta}, þvottavél\index{þvottavél}, æð\index{æð}, ör\index{ör}, auga\index{auga}, eyra\index{eyra}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

I compile it using

```
pdflatex alphabet.tex
texindy -L icelandic alphabet.idx
pdflatex alphabet.tex
```

(you may have to update `Xindy`, as I had to do).
What I'm hoping for is some kind of command, either in my `.tex` document or in some file that `Xindy` reads, but other solutions are appreciated.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165273/texindy-sorting-icelandic) is similar and has an answer that seems to work but it uses `LuaTex` while I use `LaTeX` (switching is not an option). It's also very long and technical for such a (seemingly) simple change.

**Edit:** I failed to mention that my `LaTeX` file is not utf-8 encoded and I'm not using \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, which I think might matter. I'm working on a 300+ book and I'm afraid that changing the encoding might have unexpected effects, so if there's a solution that doesn't require utf-8, that would be preferred.

Comment: Have you tried to change encoding to utf-8?

Comment: @chejnik I have tried, and I get a lot of errors and warnings concerning labels being multiply defined or `missing \endcsname inserted`. Some of them are probably due to special characters being used as labels (not very smart of those who worked on the document before me).

Comment: I guess you might rename the question to the original title, so that the answer reflects the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution can be found at question [**Texindy sorting Icelandic - Edit 2 A minimalistic version**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170370/8380) and  `LuaTex` is not required to obtain the solution.

Download the first file using a terminal and place it inside your `LaTex` folder:

```
wget http://striz7.fame.utb.cz/tex-sx/is-min/icelandicmalmin.xdy
```

**Update:** Download `iec2utf` and place all files inside your `LaTex` folder:

```
https://github.com/michal-h21/iec2utf
```

Run the following commands:

```
pdflatex alphabet
texlua iec2utf.lua <alphabet.idx >mal-temp.idx
xindy -M texindy -M icelandicmalmin-test -M mal-style -o alphabet.ind mal-temp.idx
biber alphabet
pdflatex alphabet
pdflatex alphabet
```

Example of index sorting Icelandic characters with accents:

[image]

Comment: Do I need to download the file iec2utf.lua? The second step (the texlua step) just results in a file with the text "Scriptfile iec2utf.lua not found".
Also, I don't think my file in in utf-8. Will this solution still work?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the link to the `iec2utf` files.

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work unless the file is encoded with utf-8 and with \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} in the preamble.  Is there any way to do this for a non-utf-8 encoded file?

Also, in the `xindy` step, I get multiple warnings such as 
`WARNING: define-letter-group: prefix "ä" now maps to letter group "├É"` and one error:
`ERROR: replacing location-reference-class \`"see"' is not allowed !`.
I also got these errors when I tried changing my file to utf-8 first, but in that case `pdflatex` could compile without error afterwards, and the index was correct,

Comment: I suggest to ask a new question regarding indexing a non-utf-8 encoded file.

Comment: I took your advice and asked a new question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254917/indexing-a-non-utf-8-encoded-file-with-special-characters).